В чем проблема при подключении?

подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема? при первой установке битрикс24 вылетает такая ошибка, кодировку проверил в битриксе везде utf-8 mysql тоже utf-8 файл .settings.php тоже utf-8 что не так? причем это происходит когда правишь .settings.php

Вот эта строка вылезает, когда происходит какая-то ошибка и отключен дебаг в .settings.php. Включите дебаг в этом файле и посмотрите, какая ошибка возникает.

спасибо уже разобрался) декодировал и оказалось у пользователя майскьюэль прав не былло
